# BigQuery UDF reducing all rows

Tags: google-bigquery, udf

I have the following UDF defined (note my table had an 'Id' and a 'Reading' object with subfield 'RawHex'):

```
// UDF definition
function hexdecode(row, emit) {
  emit({
    Id: row.Id,
    converted: decodeHelper(row.Reading.Raw)
  });
}

// Helper function with error handling
function decodeHelper(s) {
  try {
    return parseInt(s, 16);
  } catch (ex) {
    return s;
  }
}

// UDF registration
bigquery.defineFunction(
  'hexdecode',  // Name used to call the function from SQL

  ['Id', 'Reading.Raw'],  // Input column names

  // JSON representation of the output schema
  [{name: 'Id', type: 'STRING'},
   {name: 'converted', type: 'INTEGER'}],

  hexdecode  // The function reference
);
```

and my query is:

```
select Id, converted from 
hexdecode(
select r.Id, r.Reading.Raw from Example.TagRaw2 r
)
```

Generated from uploading the following JSON to the table Example.TagRaw2

```
{"Id":"ABC","Reading":{"Raw":"0004"}}
{"Id":"CDE","Reading":{"Raw":"000b"}}
```

I expected this to convert my column from Hex to Integer, but instead if returns a single entry that make almost no sense.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I added an example JSON to upload to try and reproduce the problem.. but it now seems to work. I will update again if I can figure out what was originally wrong, but the UDF above seems to do exactly what I want.

Comment: Why you emit 'TagId', and you define schema name as 'Id'?

Comment: Do you mind including a sample in/output?

Comment: bit hard as I'm not sure what I can put out in public - I'll try recreate the issue with a synthetic set.

Comment: ping when you do so please!

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I've added a JSON you can upload to get my Table layout... unfortunately now the query works fine...

Comment: If you have a job id from your Query History for one of the failed jobs, we can look into it.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, let me look into this later today and get back to you. Been side tracked by other work and decided to just do this conversion locally anyway. Good to get it going though.

Comment: I think you're onto the right track below, but I haven't quite got it. Here is a jobID if you want to take a look: valued-vault-111213:job_d7yoKziSgyeqDUc4gG_SgXCW5jg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question - is your Reading object a repeated column, by any chance?

If so, you'll need to do something like this:

```
function hexdecode(r, emit) {
  for (var i = 0; i < r.reading.length; ++i) {
    emit({ tag: r.Id, num: parseInt(r.reading[i].Raw, 16) });
  }
}

bigquery.defineFunction(
  'hexdecode',
  ['Id', 'reading.Raw'],
  [{name: 'tag', type: 'string'},
   {name: 'num', type: 'integer'}],
  hexdecode
);
```

If you try to access `r.reading.Raw`, this will be trying to access the `Raw` property of a JavaScript array.  This is perfectly valid JavaScript, but it's certainly not what you want since the value is undefined (null).

One handy trick is to print out the JSON string of the input record to see what the UDF is seeing as input:

```
bigquery.defineFunction(
  'jsonifyObj',
  ['Id', 'reading.Raw'],
  [{name: 'obj', type: 'string'}],
  function(r, emit) { emit({obj: JSON.stringify(r)}); }
);
```

This can help to debug problems.  I suspect the issue in this case is that your data looks more like

```
[{"Id":"ABC","Reading":[{"Raw":"0004"}, {"Raw": "00ff"}]},
 {"Id":"CDE","Reading":[{"Raw":"000b"}, {"Raw": "0012"}]}]
```

-------- Update 2015-11-17 --------

Your code has a few problems, commented NOTE below:

```
function hexdecode(row, emit) {
 for (var i = 0; i < row.reading.length; ++i) {
   // NOTE: tag and row.Id are wrong, this must be TagId and row.TagId based on your input and output specifications
   emit({ tag: row.Id,
          times: row.reading[i].Timestamp,
          // NOTE: You're making a recursive call here!  You should be calling decodeHelper() not hexdecode().
          convert: hexdecode(row.reading[i].RawCO) });
  }
}


// Helper function with error handling
function decodeHelper(s) {
  try {
    return parseInt(s, 16);
  } catch (ex) {
    return s;
  }
}

// UDF registration
bigquery.defineFunction(
  'hexdecode',  // Name used to call the function from SQL

  ['TagId', 'reading.Timestamp', 'reading.RawCO'],  // Input column names

  // JSON representation of the output schema
  [{name: 'TagId', type: 'STRING'},
   {name: 'times', type: 'INTEGER'},
   {name: 'convert', type: 'INTEGER'}],

  hexdecode  // The function reference
);
```

Your nested select returns 0 rows, so I updated to the following SQL:

```
select 
  TagID, times, convert 
from  hexdecode(
select r.TagId, r.Reading.Timestamp, r.Reading.RawCO from [table.Readings] r where r.Reading.RawCO is not NULL and r.Reading.PPM is
 not NULL
 and r.TagId = 'Tag_00000000' 
 )
```

And here is the corrected code:

```
function hexdecode(row, emit) {
  for (var i = 0; i < row.reading.length; ++i) {
    emit({TagId: row.TagId, times: row.reading[i].Timestamp, convert: decodeHelper(row.reading[i].RawCO)});
  }
}

// Helper function with error handling
function decodeHelper(s) {
  try {
    return parseInt(s, 16);
  } catch (ex) {
    return s;
  }
}

// UDF registration
bigquery.defineFunction(
  'hexdecode',  // Name used to call the function from SQL

  ['TagId', 'reading.Timestamp', 'reading.RawCO'],  // Input column names

  // JSON representation of the output schema
  [{name: 'TagId', type: 'STRING'},
   {name: 'times', type: 'INTEGER'},
   {name: 'convert', type: 'INTEGER'}],

  hexdecode  // The function reference
);
```

Comment: Awesome.. I think this is it. I'll try this and get back to you later.

Comment: Hmm this isn't quite working for me - the length of r.reading is undefined. How exactly do you print the json out?

Comment: So if you were using the code for jsonifyObj I pasted above, the corresponding select would be `SELECT obj FROM jsonifyObj(select r.Id, r.Reading.Raw from Example.TagRaw2 r)`

Comment: Sorry can't access this away from work - I will get back to you ASAP

Comment: You were right about the format of the input, but I'm still having trouble. Apparently the 'length' field is undefined. Here is a job ID: valued-vault-111213:job_-cWTofri5UVAkxNgSdnNzFSCHso

Comment: It looks like your query is referencing `r.Reading.Timestamp` and  `r.Reading.RawCO`, but the JS is referencing `r.reading`.  Does it work if you upper-case "Reading" in your JS?  The tipoff is in the error message: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` - it's not "length" that's undefined, it's the object it's being accessed from, "r.reading"

Comment: No, if I change to r.reading, then it tells me that it was 'expecting r.reading, but got r.Reading.RawCo'.

Comment: Ah, I shouldn't have spoken without checking your job.  You are accessing an undefined property, but not because of a field name mismatch.  You're accidentally making a recursive call to the UDF handler.  This would be catchable using the UDF test tool.  I've updated my answer above with full details.

Comment: Haha oops! Now I see the problem. Thank you very much for your time :-) How can I get access to the UDF test tool for the future?

Comment: I'm a bit concerned with specifics of my query being on here publicly - would you mind editing your answer to remove specific table names/values?

Comment: Re: editing - sure thing!  LMK if it looks ok to you now.

Comment: The test tool is just a simple HTML-based form : http://storage.googleapis.com/bigquery-udf-test-tool/testtool.html  It's not a perfect substitute for running queries in BQ, but it's handy for debugging issues.  If you run it in Chrome, you can set breakpoints in your code via the developer console.

Comment: Great! Thanks for all your help, and the edit looks fine.